# Cómo puedo iterar el número de una lista en python

Tags: python, bucle-for

Lo que tengo que hacer es extraer los números de un archivo txt, guardar los números y después imprimir un "Hola" dependiendo del numero encontrado en el archivo de texto.

Ejemplo

> Hola este es un archivo 5 donde se 2 están extrayendo los datos 3 hola 2 como 1 estas 5

Extraigo los numero: 5,2,3,2,1,5

Guardo los numero y quiero que me imprima lo siguiente

```
##Imprime 5 holas porque es el primer numero
Ciclo
Hola
Hola
Hola
Hola
Hola
##Imprime 2 holas porque es el siguiente numero en la lista
Ciclo
Hola
Hola
```

Y así sucesivamente con cada numero encontrado en el texto

Este es el código que tengo

```
from re import split
import re

with open('Prueba2.txt') as archivo:
    leer = archivo.read()

s = [int(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*',leer)]


for x in s:
    print("Ciclo")
    for y in s:
        print("Hola")

print(s)
```

Pero el resultado no es exactamente lo que necesito

Comment: Por favor, por la calidad del sitio, evita editar tu publicación para preguntar otra cosa. Si tenés otra duda, hacé otra publicación, tal y como hiciste hace un momento. Si no te deja publicar, esperá un tiempo. Ya revertí la edición.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre se imprime "Hola" la misma cantidad de veces porque estás imprimiendo "Hola" por cada elemento en la lista `s`. Debería ser

```
for n in s:
    print("Ciclo")
    for i in range(n):
        print("Hola")
```

Comment: Mas que suficiente, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para iterar sobre los elementos de una lista únicamente debes utilizar la función "iter()" que creará un generador. Esto creará una lista que al recorrerla con el bucle for, ira generando el siguiente valor de la variable "s" hasta que ya no haya más, una vez se acaba ya no podrás volver a llamar a la variable "s". Es más eficiente y rápido.
Aplicando eso a tu código, quedaría así:

```
import re
with open('Prueba2.txt') as archivo:
     leer = archivo.read()

s = iter(int(s) for s in re.findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*',leer))

for x in s:
    print("Ciclo", "\nHola"*x) # Aquí acortamos el código con la expresión de multiplicar el string "Hola" por un número
```

Comment: Gracias por la contribución! Sin embargo, debo aclarar algunas cosas: iter no es necesario, el generador (no función generadora) se crea escribiendo una comprensión de listas, pero con parentesis en lugar de corchetes. Un generador no crea una lista temporal, va generando valores conforme es necesario, como cualquier iterador. Eso me lleva a lo siguiente: el bucle for no se acaba hasta "terminar" el iterador.

Comment: Muchas gracias @DanteS. por estar siempre atento, código editado

Comment: De nada :D Sin embargo, veo que sigues usando la función iter, que en este caso devuelve el mismo iterador, y sigues mencionando que es una lista. La cuestión era más con la descripción que con el código.

Answer (score 0):

Estás utilizando dos bucles anidados, y en cada iteración del bucle exterior estás imprimiendo "Hola" para cada elemento en la lista s. Esto causa que se imprima "Hola" múltiples veces, incluso para los mismos elementos.

He modificado tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
from re import findall

with open('Prueba2.txt') as archivo:
    leer = archivo.read()

s = [int(s) for s in findall(r'-?\d+\.?\d*', leer)]

for x in s:
    print("Ciclo")
    for _ in range(x):
        print("Hola")

print(s)
```

Modificando el bucle interno `for y in s` por `for _ in range(x)` esto imprime 'Hola' la cantidad de veces indicado dentro del valor de `x`.